# Firefox extension don't work in Windows 7 RTM

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I used MozBackup to backup my Firefox profile and after I installed Firefox on Windows 7 I simply restored the profile using Mozback up again.

Everything worked perfectly but strangely all my extension weren't working so i uninstalled all the extensions and tried to reinstall them but i get this error

[image: firefox error]

Has anyone encountered this? Any solutions?

Comment: what does the error console log say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution from [here](http://ffextensionguru.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/tip-unexpected-installation-error-203-add-ons/) says:

> 99% of the time it is going to be
>   caused by corrupted configuration
>   files on your computer. 
> To fix this
>   problem follow these steps:
>
> 1. Close Firefox
> 2. Locate your Profile Folder
> 3. Delete the following files from your profile folder:
>
>    > extensions.ini
>    >     extensions.cache
>    >     extensions.rdf
> 4. Restart Firefox.
>
> When Firefox restarts it will
>   automatically rebuild the 3 files in
>   step #3 above and should allow you to
>   be able to install add-ons again.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using [FEBE backup extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109) next time.I am using it and I got no problem up to now.You can pack all your extensions,bookmarks etc.. into one .xpi file so next time you can restore them with a one single click after Firefox set-up.